# Codeigniter ActiveRecord: join backticking

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've a simple question: how can I use CodeIgniter's ActiveRecord `join` function? I want this:

```
LEFT JOIN cimke ON (mk_terem.id_kicsoda=5 AND mk_terem.id_target=cimke.id_cimke)
LEFT JOIN tanar ON (mk_terem.id_kicsoda=1 AND mk_terem.id_target=tanar.id_tanar)
```

But if I use `$this->db->join(cimke,"mk_terem.id_kicsoda=5 AND mk_terem.id_target=cimke.id_cimke")`, the value `5` will be between backticks.

How can I do this?

UPDATE

What I want? If `mk_terem.id_kicsoda` is 1, then I want `tanar.nev` and when  `mk_terem.id_kicsoda` is 5, I want `cimke.nev`.

The full SQL-query:

```
SELECT
terem.nev terem_nev,
elem_tipus.nev tipus_nev,
(IFNULL(cimke.nev,tanar.nev)) nev
FROM mk_terem
LEFT JOIN terem ON mk_terem.id_terem=terem.id_terem
LEFT JOIN cimke ON (mk_terem.id_kicsoda=5 AND mk_terem.id_target=cimke.id_cimke)
LEFT JOIN tanar ON (mk_terem.id_kicsoda=1 AND mk_terem.id_target=tanar.id_tanar)
LEFT JOIN elem_tipus ON (mk_terem.id_kicsoda=elem_tipus.id_kicsoda)
```

Comment: This issue has been fixed in CI v3-DEV. BTW, I [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18208300/1725764) how to hack the CI AR to achieve this, some months ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only a simple workaround, ugly, not elegant, but it works in this case:

```
$original_reserved = $this->db->_reserved_identifiers;
$this->db->_reserved_identifiers[] = 5;
$this->db->_reserved_identifiers[] = 1;
// or any other values
$this->db->join('with critical values and conditions');
// some db-stuff
$this->db->_reserved_identifiers = $original_reserved;
```

If anybody knows better please show it!

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->join('cimke', 'mk_terem.id_target = cimke.id_cimke');
$this->db->join('tanar', 'mk_terem.id_target = tanar.id_tanar');
$this->db->where('mk_terem.id_kicsoda', 5);
$this->db->where('mk_terem.id_kicsoda', 1);
```

or use

```
$this->db->query('AND_YOUR_RAW_SQL_QUERY_HERE');
```

Comment: No, this isn't good. Please consider that in table `cimke` has an item with `id_cimke` value 10 and in table `tanar` has an item with `id_tanar` value 10.

My query's result differs from your query's result (not second :)).

What I want? If `mk_terem.id_kicsoda` is 1, then I want `tanar.nev` and when `mk_terem.id_kicsoda` is 5, I want `cimke.nev`.

Comment: Added a simple answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860441/codeigniter-activerecord-join-backticking/7865482#7865482

Comment: so do `$this->db->query("
SELECT
terem.nev terem_nev,
elem_tipus.nev tipus_nev,
(IFNULL(cimke.nev,tanar.nev)) nev
FROM mk_terem
LEFT JOIN terem ON mk_terem.id_terem=terem.id_terem
LEFT JOIN cimke ON (mk_terem.id_kicsoda=5 AND mk_terem.id_target=cimke.id_cimke)
LEFT JOIN tanar ON (mk_terem.id_kicsoda=1 AND mk_terem.id_target=tanar.id_tanar)
LEFT JOIN elem_tipus ON (mk_terem.id_kicsoda=elem_tipus.id_kicsoda)
")`

Comment: Yes, I know that I can use raw sql query but many queries are dinamically created and it's comfort (and easier) to use ActiveRecord.

Sorry that I didn't answered your comment... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution would be to temporarily set the protect_identifiers off like so:

```
$this->db->_protect_identifiers = false;
```

After making the query you could set it back to `true`

Comment: I think it works only newer versions because if you check https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/database/DB_active_rec.php#L333 (333th line) you can see that `_protect_identifiers` is a function. In newest version (https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_query_builder.php) `_protect_identifiers` is a variable and `protect_identifiers` is the function.

Answer (score 0):

I know i am very answering this question very late. Just i am sharing my knowledge. It may help us to known something. If I am wrong, Please tell me. I am answering this question by the full query you posted on your question. Kindly check it below.

```
$this->db->from('mk_terem');
$this->db->select('terem.nev terem_nev, elem_tipus.nev tipus_nev, (IFNULL(cimke.nev,tanar.nev)) nev');
$this->db->join('terem','mk_terem.id_terem=terem.id_terem','left');
$this->db->join('cimke','(mk_terem.id_kicsoda=5 AND mk_terem.id_target=cimke.id_cimke)','left');
$this->db->join('tanar','(mk_terem.id_kicsoda=1 AND mk_terem.id_target=tanar.id_tanar)','left');
$this->db->join('elem_tipus','(mk_terem.id_kicsoda=elem_tipus.id_kicsoda)','left'); $this->db->get();
```

I got the query which you posted in the question as full Query. Check it below.

```
SELECT `terem`.`nev` terem_nev, `elem_tipus`.`nev` tipus_nev, (IFNULL(cimke.nev, `tanar`.`nev))` nev FROM (`mk_terem`) LEFT JOIN `terem` ON `mk_terem`.`id_terem`=`terem`.`id_terem` LEFT JOIN `cimke` ON `mk_terem`.`id_kicsoda`=`5` AND mk_terem.id_target=cimke.id_cimke) LEFT JOIN `tanar` ON `mk_terem`.`id_kicsoda`=`1` AND mk_terem.id_target=tanar.id_tanar) LEFT JOIN `elem_tipus` ON `mk_terem`.`id_kicsoda`=`elem_tipus`.`id_kicsoda)`
```

I believe everything is possible to do by codeignitor Active record. No need to execute the query in `$this->db->query()` as raw sql.

@uzsolt: I am explaining this because of the argument you made under the topic "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344769/writing-sql-queries-in-codeigniter-2-0". And I will try your other bugs you posted under the above URL too shortly and get back to you. If i am anything wrong, kindly let me know. Thanks. :)

Comment: First: thanks your answer! What version of Codeigniter? As I see in the latest (2.1.2) version doesn't try protect the condition (check https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/database/DB_active_rec.php#L340 ). But this question isn't actual yet because I've wrote a small library instead of CI's ActiveRecord and it works well for me :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you swap the conditions around AND, it will work! CodeIgniter only escapes the first part of the condition.
So, inthis should work:

```
$this->db->join('cimke',"mk_terem.id_kicsoda = 5 AND mk_terem.id_target = cimke.id_cimke", "left")
```