# Codeigniter database Join not accepting value instead of column name

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, activerecord, join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Codeigniter ActiveRecord: join backticking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860441/codeigniter-activerecord-join-backticking)

I want to give a value in the place of column name but it is not able to recognize it and it is giving me error. Here is my code:

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('users')->where('users.ID',$this->session->userdata('user_id'));
$this->db->join('contact','contact.ID = 1','left');
$result =  $this->db->get()->row_array();
```

The issue is with the join and it is not accepting value.It is giving me this error

```
error:

Unknown column '1' in 'on clause'
```

I have to use 1 because there is no relation between the tables and in the contact table there is only one row.

Comment: you should enter related table column instead of 1 like users.id

Comment: Joining tables only makes sense when they are related. I would go with two separate queries for `users` and `contact`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks every one for reply.I found an alternative,using this:
 `$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM (users) LEFT JOIN 'contact' ON contact.ID = ? WHERE users.ID = ?",array(1,$user_id));`
,doing this codeigniter does not give me any error.

Answer (score 0):

When you are going to make a join you need to make it on commons fields
the natural SQL would be:

`select * from users join contact on USERS.COMMON_FIELD = CONTACT.COMMONFIELD where users.id = $this->session->userdata('user_id')`

'translating' this to CI

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('users'));
$this->db->join('contact','contact.common_field = users=common_field');
$this->db->where('users.ID',$this->session->userdata('user_id'))
```

you have to put where it says `contact.ID = 1);` the common field between tables,

mysql join http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

CodeIgniter join: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: Thanks for reply jcho360, actually this query works "SELECT *
FROM (`users`)
LEFT JOIN 'contact` ON `contact`.`ID` = 1
WHERE `users`.`ID` = '7'"

Comment: I just need to remove those single quotes around my 1 and it will work. But till now i'm not able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I've meet this problem some time ago and I found a workaround, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860441/codeigniter-activerecord-join-backticking/7865482#7865482)!

(So this question is duplicated)

Comment: There can not be one solution to similar problems.

Comment: Yes, it's only a workaround. If you combine your queries dinamically you can't use your solution (raw query). It's a bug in ActiveRecord: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/590

(My solution: I wrote a similar lib to ActiveRecord :) )