# CodeIgniter ActiveRecord join() method wrapping numbers with backticks

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

This is my active record code in CodeIgniter:

```
$this->db->...
$this->db->join('post_likes', 'post_likes.user_id="'.$this->db->escape($online_user).'" AND post_likes.post_id=post.id', 'left');
```

And this is how it is interpreted:

```
LEFT JOIN `post_likes` ON `post_likes`.`user_id`="`3"` AND post_likes.post_id=post.id
```

it gives the error:

```
`user_id`="`3"`
```

How to write a direct number in active record?

---

Update:

removing `escape`

to test it on your computer you dont need to have a database. Just trying this code shows the error:

```
$this->db->select('*')
    ->from('mytable')
    ->join('post_likes', 'post_likes.user_id="3" AND  post_likes.post_id=post.id', 'left');
$query=$this->db->get('');
var_dump($this->db->last_query());
exit(0);
```

result:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '` AND post_likes.post_id=post.id' at line 3

SELECT * FROM (`mytable`) LEFT JOIN `post_likes` ON `post_likes`.`user_id`="`3"` AND post_likes.post_id=post.id
```

Answer (score 3):

You SHOULD not use the double quotes in SQL query:

```
$this->db->join('post_likes', "post_likes.user_id = $online_user AND post_likes.post_id=post.id", 'left');
```

#### Update:

This is a bug in the current CI stable version (fixed in v3.0-DEV), CI ActiveRecord methods (which doesn't implement really ActiveRecord) are prepared for simple usages.

I fixed this issue before by hacking the core files (by adding a parameter to join method to disable `_protect_identifires`).

There we go:

In `system/database/DB_active_rec.php` line #310, add `$escape` as 4th parameter:

```
public function join($table, $cond, $type = '', $escape = TRUE)
```

And change `$match[3] = ...` to:

```
if ($escape === TRUE)
{
    $match[3] = $this->_protect_identifiers($match[3]);
}
```

So, you can use `join($table, $cond, $type = '', $escape = FALSE)` to disable *escaping*.

In addition, setting `_protect_identifires` globally to `FALSE` is not in a correct direction.

the only option remains is using custom [`query()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = ?"
$this->db->query($sql, array(3));
```

Comment: what if the post has no like! then does it dismiss the post from showing in the query? where may omit the result.

Comment: @arumat I didn't attend you've used 'LEFT JOIN'. Just updated the answer.

Comment: I added a workbench code at the end of my question. you may look at it and run in a test environment to see how it renders for you.

Comment: @arumat I don't have your db schema, Try my solution and let me know how it works please.

Comment: you dont need to make a schema. the problem is before it runs on db.

Comment: @arumat I get `Table 'myDb.prefix_mytable' doesn't exist`. try my solution, it should works.

Comment: now @Eswara Reddy realised it is because of `$db['default']['_protect_identifiers']` for me. any way to avoid ` in this query only.

Comment: @arumat Setting `$db['default']['_protect_identifiers']` to `FALSE` increases chance of SQL injections, that's a bad practice.

Comment: so how does CI make query for you without backticks? I thought you disable `_protect_identifiers` too.

Comment: I didn't. If you use CI ActiveRecord, it automatically adds the backticks in SQL query. I just removed the quotes around the `$online_id` and in this case adding backticks would be okay. just give the solution a try.

Comment: What select * from users where id= ` 3 `  gives me is #1054 - Unknown column '3' in 'where clause'

Comment: @arumat You are right, sorry my bad. This is the CI bug, they just prepare AR methods for simple usages. I fixed this issue by hacking the core files, but I don't recommend you to do that. In addition setting `_protect_identifires` globally to `FALSE` is not in correct direction. the only option is using custom `query()`.

Comment: seems the best way is a direct query otherwise dirty solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860441/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $this->db->join('post_likes', "post_likes.user_id=$the_userid AND 
     post_likes.post_id=post.id", 'left');
```

or

```
 $this->db->join('post_likes', 'post_likes.user_id="'.$the_userid.'" AND 
         post_likes.post_id=post.id', 'left');
```

Update:

Define

```
$db['default']['_protect_identifiers']= FALSE;
```

in "application/config/database.php" at the end.

Comment: gives ` user_id ` = ` 3 ` how to get rid of ` ?

Comment: Here user_id is integer type so you don't need single quotes('').

Comment: even typing direct number of 3 without `'` or `"` gives wrapping `

Comment: @arumat the first one should work if datatype of user_id is INT.

Comment: even using `$this->db->join('post_likes', 'post_likes.user_id=3 AND post_likes.post_id=post.id', 'left');` renders 3 as " ` 3 " ` what is strange for me is that " and ` have not regard first-in-last-out pattern

Comment: I have updated my question. you may regard the end of my question.

Comment: Try with putting "post_likes.user_id=3 AND post_likes.post_id=post.id" in double quotes.

Comment: i did that: `"post_likes.user_id=3 AND post_likes.post_id=posts.id"` and gave: ... ` user_id ` = ` 3 `

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be to temporarily set the protect_identifiers off before join query, like so:

```
$this->db->_protect_identifiers = false;
```

After making join query you could set it back to `true`

Works for me in CodeIgniter version 2.1.2

Answer (score -2):

try this one

```
$this->db->join('post_likes', 'post_likes.user_id="{$online_user}" AND post_likes.post_id=post.id', 'left');
```

please let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score -2):

Dont use `$this->db->escape`

```
$this->db->join('post_likes', 'post_likes.user_id="'.$online_user.'" AND post_likes.post_id=post.id', 'left');
```